# change action mode title color

Tags: android, xml, styles

I want to change title color in Action mode.

Here is my styles.xml file

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
            <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/customTextView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="customTextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
```

But I see title in white. How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean to change the `ActionBar` title color ?

Comment: No, I want to change contextual action bar title color that appears when you long click on a view.